# The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose

The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid
version: "3.9"

```
services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
    ports:
      -"8000:8000"
    volumes:
      -./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: Kindly provide more context on the issue. Exact error message when compiling should help understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

errors when i tried to run `docker-compose up`:

> services.app.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
>
> services.app.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array

it's because of space between `-` and `"8000:8000"`

try this:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```